# Connect 'send notification' to 'add order using Extend in Use Case

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I'm trying to create a Use Case Diagram of Order System. But I'm curious if the 'send notification' and 'add order' is connected since before ordering, the inventory will check for the stock. I'm thinking of connecting the two using 'extend'. What do you think?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you wonder if use-cases are related because of some sequential or causal relationship, you are no longer in use-case analysis, but in one of the following situations:

1. **Functional analysis**: you’re doing functional decomposition, i.e. breaking down a functionality in more elementary functions (e.g. the includes for `Ship order`): this is not forbidden but leads to very complex diagrams that are difficult to read and use in practice due to unnecessary details and mixed levels of abstraction.
   Solution: don’t! Simplify your diagram and focus on user’s goals.

- Designing a **flow of activities**: this is wrong, since there shall be no order/sequential relationship between use-cases, and use-cases shall not be confused with events or preconditions(e.g. `item is not out of stock`) 
  Solution: go for an activity diagrams, which are meant for exactly this kind of  modelling.
- misusing use-cases for **user-interface design** (suspicion that all the `generate xxx` corresponds to windows to show data to the actor): this usually leads to bad user-interfaces and incomplete analysis of the user’s goals.

I think your (impressive and comprehensive) diagram corresponds to the first two situations. I recommend to simplify, focus on the user goals, and for each use case that is more complex, make an activity diagram for the flow.

I am very concerned when I see in the table “use-case(process)”, and it appears that this is an exercise you are trying to do. This is plain wrong: a use case is an actor’s goal and not a process. Processes are typically modelled with activity diagrams. If this comes from an UML tutorial, then immediately change tutorial!